# Strange Qt crash when deleting a QTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt

I've been beating my head against a Qt crash for a day now. A coworker suggested I try to simplify the situation, which I did. I *cannot* get it to crash in a small test app, but inside the app I'm working on, this silly minimal code usually crashes on the delete line (and calling deleteLater()) doesn't help -- I get the same call stack.

```
QTextEdit *blah = nullptr;
void MyClass::DoTheThing()
{
   if (blah != nullptr)
   {
       delete blah;
   }
   blah = new QTextEdit();
   blah->setText("BLAH");
   // like, literally, i'm not even attaching the QTextEdit to anything
}
```

A QPushButton triggers DoTheThing. Sometimes I get a crash immediately, sometimes it takes 15-20 tries.

```
    Qt5Cored.dll!QListData::isEmpty() Line 116  C++
    Qt5Cored.dll!QList<QObject *>::isEmpty() Line 201   C++
    Qt5Cored.dll!QObject::~QObject() Line 1106  C++
    Qt5Widgetsd.dll!QLayout::~QLayout() Line 772    C++
    Qt5Widgetsd.dll!QBoxLayout::~QBoxLayout() Line 571  C++
    [External Code] 
    Qt5Widgetsd.dll!QWidget::~QWidget() Line 1444   C++
    [External Code] 
    Qt5Cored.dll!QObjectPrivate::deleteChildren() Line 2123 C++
    Qt5Widgetsd.dll!QWidget::~QWidget() Line 1532   C++
    Qt5Widgetsd.dll!QFrame::~QFrame() Line 264  C++
    Qt5Widgetsd.dll!QAbstractScrollArea::~QAbstractScrollArea() Line 507    C++
    Qt5Widgetsd.dll!QTextEdit::~QTextEdit() Line 667    C++
```

The QList is of course the child list, which is bad data.

I've also seen a crash *constructing* the QTextEdit.

```
>   Qt5Cored.dll!QListData::isEmpty() Line 116  C++
    Qt5Cored.dll!QList<QObject *>::isEmpty() Line 201   C++
    Qt5Cored.dll!QObject::~QObject() Line 1106  C++
    Qt5Widgetsd.dll!QGesture::~QGesture() Line 123  C++
    Qt5Widgetsd.dll!QPanGesture::~QPanGesture() Line 304    C++
    [External Code] 
    Qt5Widgetsd.dll!qDeleteAll<QSet<QGesture *>::const_iterator>(QSet<QGesture *>::const_iterator begin, QSet<QGesture *>::const_iterator end) Line 320 C++
    Qt5Widgetsd.dll!qDeleteAll<QSet<QGesture *> >(const QSet<QGesture *> & c) Line 328  C++
    Qt5Widgetsd.dll!QGestureManager::filterEventThroughContexts(const QMultiMap<QObject *,enum Qt::GestureType> & contexts, QEvent * event) Line 418    C++
    Qt5Widgetsd.dll!QGestureManager::filterEvent(QWidget * receiver, QEvent * event) Line 527   C++
    Qt5Widgetsd.dll!QApplication::notify(QObject * receiver, QEvent * e) Line 2960  C++
    Qt5Cored.dll!QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject * receiver, QEvent * event) Line 1075    C++
    Qt5Cored.dll!QCoreApplication::sendEvent(QObject * receiver, QEvent * event) Line 1470  C++
    Qt5Widgetsd.dll!QWidgetPrivate::propagatePaletteChange() Line 1862  C++
    Qt5Widgetsd.dll!QWidget::setBackgroundRole(QPalette::ColorRole role) Line 4226  C++
    Qt5Widgetsd.dll!QTextEditPrivate::init(const QString & html) Line 194   C++
    Qt5Widgetsd.dll!QTextEdit::QTextEdit(QWidget * parent) Line 636 C++
```

Any idea where to start looking? I've commented out all of the surrounding code. Might be a double delete, or maybe something is trashing some shared data in Qt somewhere, but because of the semi-reproducible nature of the crash it's proving very difficult to debug. Might also be a timing issue, though none of the other threads seem to be doing anything.

Comment: `if (blah != nullptr)` -- Note -- there is no need for a `nullptr` check when issuing a `delete` call.  Calling `delete` on a `nullptr` is perfectly ok.

Comment: Well I would recommend you start small and debug it little by little from: Qt5Widgetsd.dll!QApplication::notify(QObject * receiver, QEvent * e) Line 2960  C++, It looks like you are trying to run 3000 lines of code without testing it first.... I would recommend that you write an empty main function first, if that crashes, then it is most likely a compiler problem not a coding issue, try somethin like int main(){ return 0;}

Comment: Paul, you're of course right, and I hope I would have called that out in a code review. I'm really not sure why I did that. However, if I remove it now, some of the comments here will make no sense.

Comment: @ShannonBailey I'm no QT expert, but aren't some widgets deleted by the Qt framework by issuing a `delete this;`?  If so, issuing a second `delete` call would be a double deletion error.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Sort of. If I'd done **QTextEdit *blah = new QTextEdit(widget)**, then **delete widget** would also delete blah. In the radically simplified code above, I'm not giving QTextEdit a parent, so it's up to me to manage its life cycle. Not the issue here.

That said, something must be getting tangled up... or stomping on memory. I guess I should get out my rusty memory trashing toolbox...

Comment: For what it's worth, in the real code, where I'm using a class derived from a QTextEdit, I put a breakpoint in the destructor and at the top level it's only being called once. When I said double delete I meant something internal in the Qt stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning something to nullptr:

```
QTextEdit *blah = nullptr;
```

Which basically means you never allocated any memory to it in the first place, so when you call:

```
delete blah;
```

You are deleting something that does not exist.

Comment: This is not correct.  Issuing a `delete` on a `nullptr` is perfectly ok.

Comment: You might say: "I checked the nullptr condition!!" Well think about it, QtextEdit has a destructor by itself, so when you delete the QtextEdit, it will do a double deletion, after the function is done.....

Comment: No need for this comment, @YunfeiChen.  He was just explaining that delete on a nullptr is acceptable.

Comment: @ShannonBailey The problem isnt you checking or not, the real problem is that your blah is always nullptr, but Qtextedit has a destructor, when you call the destructor, it crashes....

Comment: 1. delete nullptr is a noop, and is perfectly valid
2. note that i'm already checking for null, even though i don't need to
3. not sure why the QTextEdit would be deleted once the function is done. pointers don't tend to work like that.

Comment: @ShannonBailey did you read?? https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html Look at the virtual function....

Comment: @ShannonBailey Destructors are called automatically....

Comment: destructors are called automatically for objects allocated on the stack. not if they're on the heap, though.

Comment: I think you need a good book on objects, there is no need for a destructor at all if objects are on stack....

Comment: if an object on the stack allocates heap memory in its constructor, it needs a destructor that will release that memory.

however, this is getting a bit into the weeds.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so this looks like memory trashing from something completely unrelated. Early returning from a fragile function that uses Qt objects but has nothing to do with UI prevents this crash.

Nothing mysterious in Qt, nothing to see here, move along.